# Do Chain Devils' Animated Chains restrain creatures on a grapple?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, animated-objects

The [Chain Devil](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/chain-devil) can make an attack that will grapple and restrain the target on a hit.

> Chain. Melee Weapon Attack: +8 to hit, reach 10 ft., one target. Hit: 11 (2d6 + 4) slashing damage. **The target is grappled (escape DC 14) if the devil isn't already grappling a creature. Until this grapple ends, the target is restrained** and takes 7 (2d6) piercing damage at the start of each of its turns.

I understand that the Chain Devil, when making its Chain attack will restrain the target, but it is not stated in the statblock anywhere if the chains animated with the Animate Chains action also restrain creatures that they grapple.

> Animate Chains (Recharges after a Short or Long Rest). Up to four chains the devil can see within 60 feet of it magically sprout razor-edged barbs and animate under the devil's control, provided that the chains aren't being worn or carried.
>   Each animated chain is an object with AC 20, 20 hit points, resistance to piercing damage, and immunity to psychic and thunder damage. When the devil uses Multiattack on its turn, it can use each animated chain to make one additional chain attack. An animated chain can grapple one creature of its own but can't make attacks while grappling. An animated chain reverts to its inanimate state if reduced to 0 hit points or if the devil is incapacitated or dies.

My assumption is that the chains can only grapple and not restrain, but if there is any reason why that might not be the case or if there's an obvious reason why they can't I would love to hear it.

Comment: Related: [Can a Chain Devil's Animated Chains move?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119693)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes.

The devil can use each chain to make an additional chain attack. "Chain attack" simply refers to the attack the devil can already make that's titled "Chain", which you've quoted, and includes both the grapple and the restraining effect.

"An animated chain can grapple one creature of its own" should be read as saying that, for purposes of the "if the devil is already grappling a creature" limitation, it's the animated chain (and not the devil) that's grappling them.

Answer (score 0):

Things do exactly what they say.  So, as written, the animated chains grapple, not restrain. This is different from the Chain Devil's chain weapon.

> An animated chain can **grapple** one creature of its own but can't make attacks while grappling.

Comment: I believe this sentence is just to clarify that the chain can't keep attacking once it's grappling, which is different from the Chain Devil's standard Chain attack.  In all other respects it's identical to a Chain attack.

So it is doing exactly what is written - it's an additional chain attack, with the exception that it can't make an attack when the previously described grappling effect is happening.  And the previously described grappling effect includes restraining the target.